# Why can't I instantiate and control the Dropzone class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The photo keeps width of 100px and height of 100px. Why it doesn't the following code work?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(“div#myDropzone”, { 
        url: "./data.php",
        enqueueForUpload: true,
        thumbnailWidth: 200,
        thumbnailHeight: 200
    });

   });
</script>

<form action="#" class="dropzone" id="myDropzone">
<inpit name="file" type="file">
</form>
```

[Click here for a working demo](http://huang.julycui.com/message/index.php/test#)

Comment: You seem to have typographic quotation marks in there: `“div#myDropzone”` - replace them with regular `"` quotes, that might be the problem.

Comment: you have syntax error also in your markup at <inpit name... this should be <input name...>

Comment: @LarsEbert In addition, the OP's selector is completely invalid. There is no `div#myDropzone`. `myDropzone` is a `<form>`. Also I removed the PHP tag as this has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a multitude of problems with your code, as was pointed out in the comments section above by *@LarsEbert* and *@Harry*.

**Problem 1:**

You appear to be using typographica quotation marks as opposed to standard quotation marks. Modify your code like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDropzone", { 
        url: "./data.php",
        enqueueForUpload: true,
        thumbnailWidth: 200,
        thumbnailHeight: 200
    });
});
```

**Problem 2:**

You input statement has a typographical error associated with it. Change your input to be the following:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input name="file" type="file">
<!-- or XHTML -->
<input name="file" type="file" />
```

**Problem 3:**

In addition, you're JavaScript selector for you new *Drop Zone* is `"div#myDropzone"`. This ID corresponds to the one associated with the `<form>` element shown, not a `<div>`. The selector should probably be changed to `"form#myDropzone"`. If you do have a `<div id="myDropzone">` then your markup is invalid as an ID has to be unique.

Comment: I had try changed the "div#myDropzone" to "form#myDropzone".but it still does not work.I just follow the document of dropzone to write,it should be "div#myDropzone".It is fixed format. And I did not find any different between the code of problem 1 and my code.